# validateRequest="false" is not working in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, asp.net-2.0

I am working on an ASP.NET 2.0 application.

In my page I have:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminPanel/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="SEO.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdminPanel_SEO" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and on page directives I have `validateRequest="false"`. It works locally but on IIS online it does not work.. Any idea guys?

Comment: can you add your directives here so we can see what you're doing exactly?

Comment: What ASP.NET version is "IIS Online"? If its running 4.0 (regardless of your compiled version), you need to add  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> into the web.config

Comment: What is your project setup as ..? `2.0, 3.5, or 4.0` if it's 4.0 roll it back to `3.5 .net framework` and it should work.. there is a known error in 4.0 for that it does not work also based on `StingyJack's` suggestion `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` you need to do this as well but you may need to add some other scripting in your .config file.. I had this same issue back in `October of 2012`

Comment: IIS version is 6.0 and my Project Setup is 2.0

Comment: @emd i have added Page Directives in the edited version.. see my Post.

Comment: Any more Ideas Guys... None is working from above suggested solutions.

Comment: Have you added `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` in `web.config`

Comment: @RanaDotnet Please submit your solution as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

This is the thing i had to update in web.config file and it was working fine after that.

Thanks